# find if there exists a common element in 2 arrays

Tags: java

Given two arrays of integers, how can you efficiently find out if the two arrays have an element in common?

Can somebody come up with a better space complexity than this (I would appreciate pointing errors in the program too, thanks!!).

Is it possible to solve this using a XOR?

```
public boolean findcommon(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
  Set<int> s = new Hashset<int>();
  for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
    if(!s.contains(arr1[i]))
      s.add(arr1[i]);
  }
  for(int i=0;i<arr2.length;i++) {
    if(s.contains(arr2[i]))
        return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `Set<int>` is not valid in Java.

Comment: Do you want a C or a Java solution?!

Comment: Well, if you could `sort` the arrays first, then you can restrict your search to elements of `arr1` that are at least as big as `arr2[0]` (or vice versa).

Comment: @Eng.Fouad shouldn't that be `Set<Integer>`?

Comment: Another way is to use hashing...

Comment: If you're optimizing for speed, the OP's solution is optimal.  If you're optimizing for memory, the optimal solution is just a straight-up double `for` loop in quadratic time.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking for a more space efficient solution:

When you accept a runtime of O(n log n) and are allowed to change the arrays, you could sort them and then do a linear pass to find the common elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do it ONCE, then you can't do better than time complexity O(n+m) where n and m are the respective lengths of arrays. You have to go through the input in both arrays, there is no choice (how else will you look at all the input?), so just the input processing will have that complexity, there is no point in doing something more efficient. If you need to keep searching as the arrays grow, that's a different discussion.

So the question with your suggested way of implementing comes down to how long does "contains" take? Since you're using a Hashset, contains is constant time O(1), so you get to O(n) to create the hashset and O(m) to verify elements in the second array. 
Put together, O(n+m). Good enough ;)

If you're looking for improved space complexity, you first of all need to be able to make changes to the original arrays. But I don't think there's any way to use less additional space than O(n) and still perform in O(n+m) time.

Note: I'm not sure what XOR you are thinking of. If you're thinking of bit-wise or logical XOR, there's no use for it here. If you're thinking of Set XOR, it doesn't matter if it's logically useful or not, as it's not in the implementation of Java Sets, so you would still have to roll your own.

Comment: Note that for many collisions, HashSet's contains as well as add will be worse than O(1).

Comment: Sure, but we're using the HashSet to store unique 32bit numbers here, so not expecting too much trouble with collisions.

Comment: Yeah, that was quite nitpicky.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your solution only attempts to find if there is an element that exists in both arrays, the following is code that will do it for you:

```
 public boolean findCommon(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
      HashTable hash = new HashTable();
      for (item : arr1){
         if !(hash.containsKey(item)){
            hash.put(item, "foo");
         }
      }
      for (item : arr2){
         if (hash.containsKey(item)){
           return(true);
         }
      }
      return(false);
 }
```

This does still have a worst case complexity of O(n) for two arrays which do not share single element. If as is suggested by your initial question what you're worried about is Space Complexity (eg, you'd be happy to accept a performance hit if you didn't have to store the HashTable), you could go for something along these lines:

```
    public boolean findCommon(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){
        for (item : arr1){
           for(item2 : arr2){
               if(item ==item2){
                   return(true);
               }
           }
        }
        return(false);
    }
```

That would solve your Space Complexity issue, but would have the (objectively terrible) Time Complexity of O(n^2).

This could be simplified if you were to put more parameters around it (Say you happen to know that at least one of the arrays is sorted, or better yet, both are sorted).

But in the wildcard example you asked I believe it really will come down to O(n) with a HashTable for Space Complexity, or O(n^2) with less space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve space occupation (this is the question right?) with an algoritm of order O(n*m). Just take every pair of elements and compare them... This is awful in time but does not use any additional memory. Otherwise you could sort the two array in place (if you are allowed to modify them) and find the common elements in O(max(n,m)).